# How to get/set the userIdentity when AuthenticationMode is Passive in Azure Active directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have set the AuthenticationMode to passive and using explicit challenge to redirect to azure login page.

This works well, but I need a programmatical way to find out if the user is authenticated or not. I also want to utilize the user Name, but it is not availble in HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.

Please let me know where from I can get this information?

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType="a",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance2, tenant2, SignUpSignInPolicyId),
                ClientId = clientId2,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri2,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                CallbackPath= new PathString("/Home/index"),
            });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "b",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/Home/contact"),
            });


    public void Redirect1()
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, "b");
    }

    public void Redirect2()
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, "a");
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the code for authentication configuration?

Comment: Code has been added.

Comment: Hmm, your callback paths probably should not match to existing routes. They are typically something like `/oidc-callback`. You do need to specify different ones for the two middleware.

Comment: I changed the callback path, but user.identity.IsAuthenticated is false. It does work in case I set AuthenticationMode to Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not caused by `AuthenticationMode`, you shouldn't specify the `CallbackPath`. If you set this parameter, then the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler will only listen for posts at this address. So you are not able to handle the redirect from Azure AD successfully.

Here is the code for using the multiple OpenId connect OWIN comments for your reference:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = authority,
    AuthenticationType = "aad1",
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:2803/",
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri= "http://localhost:2803/"
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "5efa8abc-13dc-4681-83f5-c6fde071xxxx",
    Authority = authority2,
    AuthenticationType = "aad2",
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:2803/",
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri= "http://localhost:2803/"
});
```

Then we can use the `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` check whether the user is sign-in.

### Update

AccountController.cs:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public void SignIn(string provider,string ReturnUrl = "/default")
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = ReturnUrl }, provider);
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies["provider"].Value = provider;
        }
    }
    public void SignOut()
    {
        var provider = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["provider"].Value;
        Request.Cookies.Clear();
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            provider, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    }

    public void EndSession()
    {
        // If AAD sends a single sign-out message to the app, end the user's session, but don't redirect to AAD for sign out.
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

Login buttons on the login page:

```
    <input type="button" value="AzureAD-aad1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SignIn", "Account",new { provider="aad1"} )'" />
    <input type="button" value="AzureAD-aad2" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SignIn", "Account",new { provider="aad2"} )'" />
```

Here is a figure which captured the request using Fiddler:
[image]

Comment: This did not work. It falls into infinite loop, if callbackPath is not provided.

Comment: by infinite loop I mean, azure login page redirects to website root path, then website redirects to the page (authorized) which was accessed. Since user identity is not set, it again redirects to azure's login page.

Comment: We should set the redirect_uri which doesn't require authorize. After users enter their username/password Azure AD will redirect(POST) to the URI, and the OWIN comment will hand the response and enable the users sign-in and redirect to the page they want to visit. I will post the detailed code sample and a figure to demonstrate it.

Comment: Initially removed the CallbackPath, and it did not work and then after rewriting some stuff, it worked (Don't know what made it work apart from removing CallbackPath).